486 pc power source problem
My 486 pc won't start when using P8 and P9 cable from power supply. It will start when only used P9 cable. Is it correct that 486 system only use P9 cable? Otherwise, how to solve to use P8 & P9?

Have you checked whether Power Good (orange, pin 1 of P8) is high?

I've tested, it is 5 V

A likely scenario is that motherboard or peripheral card shorts one of the voltages on P8 and supply does not start. For proper operation of peripherals needing the other voltages, both P8 and P9 are needed.
